# Typed property must not be accessed before initialization with ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine, php-8

In project of Symfony 6.2 and PHP 8.1
Issue with initialisation of ArrayCollection

**I done this into my entity :**

```
#[OneToMany(targetEntity: CarItem::class, mappedBy: 'car')]
private ?Collection $items;
```

**And my construct function of this entity :**

```
public function __construct()
{
    dump('test');
    $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**But when I need to access item like this :**

```
public function getItems(): Collection
{
    return $this->items;
}
```

**It tell me that :**

Typed property App\Entity\Module\Car::$items must not be accessed before initialization

I understand that I need to initialize my items variable before access this but I do that into my __construct method before.

**Why PHP tell me that ?**

All web search tell about simple function or examples with arrayCollection do like me...

*What can I do for access items in a Car object exist into database ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello fix your code this way :

```
#[OneToMany(targetEntity: CarItem::class, mappedBy: 'car')]
private ?Collection $items = null;
```

And

```
public function getItems(): ?Collection
{
    return $this->items;
}
```

If you do not want to do that you will have to remove the `?` from type hinting.

Like this :

```
#[OneToMany(targetEntity: CarItem::class, mappedBy: 'car')]
private Collection $items;
```

By the way, for any other reader, this problem is not related to symfony, its only php type hinting logic from the author project.

Comment: OK solution is type-hinting all part of entity to null possibility

Comment: @darkomen if you type hint using ?string ?int ?whatever, always "= null" your attribute. Not needed if you do not type hint to nullable. To be precise. 
?string mean the variable can be a string or null.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible Doctrine Proxies are cached. Be sure to clear any cache you might have.